# How can I install ithir package?

Tags: r, package

I have analyses my soil samples and going to map using digital soil mapping, but `ithir` package is challenging me to be installed.

Comment: Is this related to html? Which language is this? Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet.

Comment: I assume you're working in R. What kind of problems are you facing?

Answer (score 2):

To install the ithir R package:

The devtools package has a function to allow installation of R packages from the Bitbucket code repo.

```
install.packages("devtools") 
library(devtools)
install_bitbucket("brendo1001/ithir/pkg")
```

You may want to read some further information about [Getting spatial in R](http://smartdigiag.com/DSM_book/pdfs/P3_1_RGIS_2017.pdf) (PDF).

Answer (score 0):

The following R command should definitely work.

```
install.packages("ithir", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```