# Unable to download the package "ithir"

Tags: r, package

I am busy with soil maps in R, and I am using the texbook "Using R for digital soil mapping". I am required to use the package "ithir" for relevant exercises, but I can't seem to find the package on CRAN. Is the package still available for download somewhere? Thanks!

I tried using CRAN, as well as other repositories like GitHub or Bioconductor. But I don't seem to manage.

Comment: googling your question title suggested https://stackoverflow.com/q/58271031/3358272 (so it's a good question title)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install ithir package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58271031/how-can-i-install-ithir-package)

Comment: Try: `install.packages("ithir", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`, although it has some out-dated dependencies. Your other option if you're comfortable with code is if you can't get the package to download, go to the [files](https://rdrr.io/rforge/ithir/f/) page and implement any functions you need locally